# How to prevent an encrypted APFS volume from automatically mounting?

Tags: mount, high-sierra, disk-volume, apfs

I tried adding the following line to /etc/fstab, but it doesn't work:

```
UUID=FF9DBDC4-F77F-3F72-A6C2-26676F39B7CE none apfs rw,noauto
```

I confirmed that it does work with unencrypted APFS volumes.

For encrypted HFS+ volumes you have to add the password to the keychain, but this workaround doesn't seem to work with encrypted APFS.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed that is the case, even in Mojave (Beta 2).

I have a solution which is *quite a hack*, but it works. It consists in creating a login script that unmounts the disk using diskutil after a delay.

### Create login script

Putting it in home folder for simplicity

```
nano ~/unmountDisk.sh
```

put the following in it (replace `Macintosh\ HD` with the disk name you want to unmount, if needed)

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 20  # don't do it immediately, wait until it is mounted
diskutil unmount Macintosh\ HD
```

save (ctrl-x then y, enter). Then make executable

```
chmod a+x ~/unmountDisk.sh
```

### Create launchd agent

```
nano ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.username.unmountDisk.plist
```

put the following in it (note: replace `username` with your username, especially after `/Users/`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>my.username.unmountDisk</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array><string>/Users/username/unmountDisk.sh</string></array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Finally, enable it

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.username.unmountDisk.plist
```

This should get the disk auto-unmounted shortly after login. If it doesn't work, maybe increase the delay (it was 20 seconds in the example). You can check if it works by opening Finder immediately after logging in; you should see the disk unmounting itself after a few seconds.

### Make disk-read only

I also noticed that fstab can make the disk read only (could be done as well, for safety).

```
sudo vifs
```

then press `G` `o` and paste

```
LABEL=Macintosh\040HD none apfs ro
```