# Prevent encrypted APFS volume on partition to automount / ask for password on login - Catalina

Tags: finder, catalina, mount, automount

I know [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374788/unmounted-volume-asks-for-password-at-login) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301023/how-to-prevent-an-encrypted-apfs-volume-from-automatically-mounting) [have](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39344/is-it-possible-to-disable-auto-mount-of-external-devices) [been](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367942/how-to-auto-mount-a-secondary-encrypted-hdd-on-boot) [asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310574/how-to-prevent-auto-mounting-of-a-volume-in-macos-high-sierra) [before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361523/how-to-prevent-auto-mounting-of-encrypted-apfs-volumes-by-diskarbitrationd) but I just can't believe this can't be solved, so I am going to ask again with specific details.

I have two partitions that are bootable on the internal drive of my Mac running macOS Catalina 10.15.7. Both are encrypted APFS volumes.

Whenever I log in to one of them, I am getting a promt, asking me for the password of the other. I do not want to **store the password in the keychain** to work around the prompt (for security reasons), in fact I do not want the other volume to be automatically mounted at all.
All I want is to be able to **choose the boot volume on startup** (via the [Opt] key).

---

I tried

1. adding this line to my `/etc/fstab` using `vifs`:

```
UUID=<UUID of the volume> none apfs rw,noauto
```

but this does not prevent the prompt from appearing.

2. changing the volume role via

```
diskutil ap changeVolumeRole <diskId> D
```

but this returns the error: `Error setting APFS Volume role: Unable to set the APFS Volume Role (-69599)`

---

Is there seriously no way of preventing disks from being automounted?
Can the Finder be at leat taught to not ask for the password?

Comment: idk the exact syntax rules for fstab, but I keep drives unmounted at boot with `UUID=[UUID] none auto noauto`

Comment: @Tetsujin and this works with Catalina?

Comment: I don't have any Mac with Catalina to test. Try it, it will take 5 minutes.

Comment: @Tetsujin this does not work, unfortunately. The prompt keeps popping up.

Comment: The /etc/fstab UUID=[UUID] none auto noauto trick now works  in Big Sur 11.2.

Comment: Thanks @PlinkPanther, you are right!
I added an answer for people looking for an clear description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Starting with MacOS BigSur 11.1.** the `/etc/fstab/` solution works (again):

1. find the volume label from the volume name:
   `diskutil list | grep <volume name>`
   the last entry (e.g. `disk2s2`) is the volume label.
2. find out the volume UUID from the volume label
   `diskutil info <volume label> | grep "Volume UUID"`
3. open `/etc/fstab` for editing:
   `sudo vifs`
4. add a line preventing the auto-mount of the volume:
   `UUID=<volume uuid> none auto noauto`

Here's a complete example:

```
> diskutil list | grep "Macintosh HD2 - Data"
2:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD2 - Data⁩       341.8 GB   disk2s2

> diskutil info disk2s2 | grep "Volume UUID"
Volume UUID:               C58A1BDC-593C-4854-B954-702A73ABD67C

> sudo vifs
# add the following line:
UUID=C58A1BDC-593C-4854-B954-702A73ABD67C none auto noauto
```

On the next reboot the popup asking for the password will no longer appear.