# I want to not auto-mount a partition, but I messed up: /etc/fstab asking for encryption password and does nothing (macOS Ventura)

Tags: macos, terminal, ventura, automount

I want to have two partitions, one for home and one for work, but do not want the partitions to “see” each other, hence not-automounting the partition came in mind.

So I made two partitions, and then I went into Terminal, looked up the UUID for "work", opened up `sudo vifs` and entered the following:

```
UUID=<..> none APFS rw, noauto.
```

I pressed <kbd>escape</kbd> and then entered <kbd>:X</kbd> to close the file. It did not do anything, then I thought it must be because it is encrypted. So I entered:

```
UUID=<..> none APFS encrypted rw, noauto
```

Then I pressed <kbd>escape</kbd> followed by <kbd>:X</kbd>, but here `sudo vifs` asks me the encryption password. Here I messed up, I know. I do not know what to do, so I entered the normal admin password but it will not save and exit. So I stopped the file and know I get a notice that I need to choose between quit, delete etc. I did a bunch of options and I am stuck. It now says swap files found.

[image: My Terminal screen]

At this moment I repeated steps and nothing helped. I got it to go back to a file that says the first line `:UUID=<..> none APFS rw, noauto`. But when I try to alter it and press <kbd>escape</kbd> followed by <kbd>:X</kbd>, it will still ask for the encryption password. I tried using the admin password of that partition, but I need to enter it again and then nothing. When I try to close `/etc/fstab`, it will ask if I want to terminate the process.

The thing that I want is that `sudo vifs` is normal again. Can you help get the `sudo vifs` file normal again?

Then I want to add the line like Alexander Presber said ([Prevent encrypted APFS volume on partition to automount / ask for password on login - Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404936/prevent-encrypted-apfs-volume-on-partition-to-automount-ask-for-password-on-lo/412690#412690)):

```
UUID=C58A1BDC-593C-4854-B954-702A73ABD67C none auto noauto
```

Hopefully this line with "auto" knows what format it is and hopefully it will not ask for the encryption key.

Comment: Entering `:X` in Vi will encrypt the currently edited file, something you for sure don't want to do with `/etc/fstab` (the proper way to save and quit is Escape, followed by `:wq`). Assuming you have a shell prompt: Does `cat /etc/fstab` show readable text or something gibberish like `VimCrypt~03!z`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is coming from using the wrong keyboard commands to exit `vi`. Applied correctly, the answer to [Prevent encrypted APFS volume on partition to automount / ask for password on login - Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404936/prevent-encrypted-apfs-volume-on-partition-to-automount-ask-for-password-on-lo/412690#412690) should work in your case as well.

- Get the UUIDs for the drives/partitions you want to **NOT** automount on start
- Run `sudo vifs`
- Add the lines

```
UUID=<UID of work partition> none auto noauto
UUID=<UID of home partition> none auto noauto
```

- Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>
- Type `:wq` to write the file to disk and quit `vi`.

You can check whether your update was successful by running `cat /etc/fstab` and looking for the lines you've inserted.

Comment: Dear nohillside,

It worked with ":wq", thank you. The partition "Work" does not show up, but Work - Data still mounts and asked for its password. So, finding that UUID is next, but will do that tomorrow. This was already huge. Hence my next question: "Is there a book which teaches you "terminal" and all its functions?

Comment: @VidsYOH There are tons of guides and tutorials on how to use shells :-)